# Issues installing dbt-postgres in mac M2

Tags: postgresql, dbt, dbt-postgres

After running `pip3 install dbt-postgres`, when running `dbt --version` I can't see the plug in?

Is anybody else having this issue? thanks!

[image]

Comment: can you show output of `pip freeze`, just to be sure it's installed into the right venv?

Comment: thanks but this has been solved. had to unplug the snowflake plug in and then install again the postgres plug in